# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context on function that returns "some View"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to generate a list of buttons with a function and array in Swift. If I hardcode each value, it outputs as expected but to save space I want to use a function to generate the list and then return `some View`. The issue I'm having is that I'm getting the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

when running:

```
func socialButtons() -> some View {
    let buttons = [
        (icon: "twitter", url: "https://twitter.com/joe_scotto"),
        (icon: "instagram", url: "https://instagram.com/joe_scotto"),
        (icon: "youtube", url: "https://youtube.com/joe_scotto"),
        (icon: "reddit", url: "https://reddit.com/u/joe_scotto"),
        (icon: "email", url: "mailto:contact@joescotto.com"),
    ]
        
    return HStack {
        Group {
            ForEach(0 ..< buttons.count) { button in
                Link(destination: URL(buttons[button].url!), label: {
                    Image(buttons[button].icon)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error specifically is on the line where I'm saying `return HStack {`

Comment: Extra comma in array

Comment: @cora: That is not the problem. A comma after the last element in an array (or dictionary or set) literal is valid in Swift, e.g. `let a = [1, 2, 3,]`

Comment: @Martin R thanks, good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI just mis-detected place of error - the URL is incorrectly created.

Here is fixed part. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
Link(destination: URL(string: buttons[button].url)!, label: {
    Image(buttons[button].icon)
})
```